# Rendering points, lines, segments interactively in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I am new to Qt and I want to use Qt to make interactive geometry programs using CGAL. I would like the user to input, say points, segments, using the mouse and then push a button to get a CGAL algorithm working on the input.

My environment is **CGAL 4.5, Qt 5.6** and **QtCreator 3.6.1** on an **Ubuntu 14.04 machine.**

CGAL has builtin support for its objects to be 
rendered using the QtGraphicsViewFramework (http://doc.cgal.org/latest/GraphicsView/index.html )

I don't know how to render CGAL objects -- points, lines, rays, polygons --  onto a Qt window. The page I linked to above assumes a knowledge of Qt to get an application working, and so is not  helpful to a Qt beginner.

Thus far, I have created a Qt widgets application project using QtCreator. From what I know, I need to modify the `mainwindow.ui` file graphically inside QtCreator by dragging and dropping different kinds of widgets onto it and then map signals calling CGAL functions onto slots of whatever the drawing canvas widget will be. (Is this correct? I am shaky on the signals and slots mechanism)

***MY QUESTION IS***....which widget do I place onto the window as a drawing canvas? Two relevant widgets seem to be `GraphicsView` and `OpenGL widgets` 
under the DisplayWidgets menu. But how do I use them?

Comment: Check out the documentation for QPainter, both graphics items and widgets use it for drawing. Also, it is Qt, not QT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no CGAL experience, but I can give you some Qt-related hints:

1. Use the `QGraphicsView` + `QGraphicsScene`. If you want, you can enable OpenGL support like this:

   ```
   QGraphicsView view = new QGraphicsView(parentWindow);
   view->setViewport(new QOpenGLWidget(view));
   ```
2. To draw CGAL objects you have to use either provided *graphics item classes* (`CGAL::Qt::TriangulationGraphicsItem`, `CGAL::Qt::VoronoiGraphicsItem`, ...) or derive your own from the `CGAL::Qt::GraphicsItem`. To add an item to the scene, use the `QGraphicsScene::addItem()` method.
3. To navigate (pan + zoom) the view, CGAL provides the  `CGAL::Qt::GraphicsViewNavigation` class. This is how to use it:

   ```
    CGAL::Qt::GraphicsViewNavigation* navFilter = new  CGAL::Qt::GraphicsViewNavigation(view);
    view->viewport()->installEventFilter(navFilter);
   ```